# Still not able to print class with __str__

Tags: android, string, termux

```
class student(object):
 def __init__(self, grade, clas):
  self.grade=grade
  self.clas=clas

def __str__(self):
 return "test"

mark=student("f","freshman")
print(mark)
```

---

This is result
<**main**.student object at 0xb33eb2d0>

Learning python through termux on an android

Comment: check the indentation of your `__str__` it must be in the `class student`

Comment: Feel like an idiot. That was it. Used to indenting for me, my bad

Answer (score 0):

**From:** [Python_syntax_and_semantics#Indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Indentation)

> Python uses whitespace to delimit control flow blocks (following the off-side rule). Python borrows this feature from its predecessor ABC: instead of punctuation or keywords, it uses indentation to indicate the run of a block.

So your code should be:

```py
class student(object):
  def __init__(self, grade, clas):
    self.grade=grade
    self.clas=clas
  def __str__(self):
    return "test"
```